# Set $.prop() without triggering change

Tags: jquery

```
<li>
 <input type="checkbox" id="master" />
   <ul>
   <li>
     <input type="checkbox" />

$('input').bind('change', function() {}); // exists elsewhere, cannot change
```

When I click the top level input, I want to set `.prop('checked', true)` for all of its children, but I want to **avoid** triggering the `change` event for each child checkbox.

How could I set `.prop('checked', true)` to an input without triggering `change`?

Edit: (expanding)

```
$('#master').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('input').each(function(n, in) {
        $(in).prop('checked', true); // this triggers a change event that I need to stop
    });
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you are describing is the default functionality.  Changing an element from javascript does not fire the change event.

http://jsfiddle.net/8JsP4/

Notice how if you click on a checkbox in the example, you get an alert, but if you click the button, no alert.

Comment: I think to recreate my symptom, you'd have to use an upper level checkbox to check all of the lower level boxes instead of a separate button

Comment: Still not a problem http://jsfiddle.net/8JsP4/1/  Perhaps you can reproduce the issue in my fiddle?

Comment: Hang on, just looked at your edit, your code won't do anything.  `$(this).find(...` will return nothing as `this` is an input which does not **contain** anything.  Is your html actually different than what you posted?

Comment: woops, that was a typo.. i meant to seek from the top level's parent `li`

Comment: you know, it must be a method that gets called later in the chain that is toggling the checked attribute. thanks for helping. the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: "The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus." No focus change means no change event. http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents

Answer (score 1):

try to unbind the onchange listener, then bind it again once the property has been set.

Answer (score 1):

Right now your selector targets all `input` elements. You can give your main checkbox an Id, and the others a common class.

```
<li>
<input id="main-chk"type="checkbox" />
   <ul>
   <li>
     <input class="children" type="checkbox" />

    $('li:first').bind('change', function() {
       $(this).find('li').prop('checked', 'checked');
    }); // exists elsewhere, cannot change
```

Comment: i'd need to do this without ids/classes. just based on ul/li/input hierarchy