# Manage checkboxes' functions with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select input:

```html
<select size="1" name="filter" style="width:90px;" id="priority_filter" onchange="filter_user_trainings();">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="optional">Optional</option>
  <option value="mandatory">Mandatory</option>
  <option value="essential">Essential</option>
  <option value="custom">Custom</option>
</select>

<div style="width: 50%; text-align: right; float: right">
  <input type="checkbox" id="opt_box" onchange="somestuff()">Optional
  <input type="checkbox" id="mand_box" onchange="somestuff()" checked="checked">Mandatory
  <input type="checkbox" id="ess_box" onchange="somestuff()">Essential                           
</div>
```

And a jQuery code:

```js
switch(priority_filter){
  case 'all':
    $("#opt_box").attr({checked: "checked"});
    $("#mand_box").attr({checked: "checked"});
    $("#ess_box").attr({checked: "checked"});
    break;

  case 'optional' :
    $("#opt_box").attr({checked: "checked"});
    $("#mand_box").removeAttr("checked");
    $("#ess_box").removeAttr("checked");
    break;

  case 'essential' :
    $("#ess_box").attr({checked: "checked"});
    $("#mand_box").removeAttr("checked");
    $("#opt_box").removeAttr("checked");
    break;

  case 'mandatory' :
    $("#mand_box").attr({checked: "checked"});
    $("#opt_box").removeAttr("checked");
    $("#ess_box").removeAttr("checked");

  case 'custom' :
    $("#mand_box").attr({checked: "checked"});
    $("#opt_box").removeAttr("checked");
    $("#ess_box").removeAttr("checked");
    break;    
}
```

I want to call the function in the "onchange" attr.  when the js switch the checkboxes' values but it does not works. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#opt_box").on('click',function(){
     if($(this).is(':checked')){
        // do your work here
     }
 });
```

Comment: Notoriously fails on `IE` (lt 8), for which the `click` event is a valid alternative.

Comment: is it possible to make it work only with onclick or onchange or sg?

Comment: you can do this in `somestuff()` function which is called `onChange`  just use this in your function `if($("#checkBoxId").is(':checked')){

         // do your work here
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select size="1" name="filter" style="width:90px;" id="priority_filter" onchange="filter_user_trainings(this);">
```

JS

```
function filter_user_trainings(obj){
      var priority_filter=$(obj).val();
  switch(priority_filter){
     case 'all':
        $("#opt_box").attr({checked: "checked"});
        $("#mand_box").attr({checked: "checked"});
        $("#ess_box").attr({checked: "checked"});
    break;

    case 'optional' :
        $("#opt_box").attr({checked: "checked"});
        $("#mand_box").removeAttr("checked");
        $("#ess_box").removeAttr("checked");
    break;

    case 'essential' :
        $("#ess_box").attr({checked: "checked"});
        $("#mand_box").removeAttr("checked");
        $("#opt_box").removeAttr("checked");
    break;

    case 'mandatory' :
        $("#mand_box").attr({checked: "checked"});
        $("#opt_box").removeAttr("checked");
        $("#ess_box").removeAttr("checked");

    case 'custom' :
        $("#mand_box").attr({checked: "checked"});
        $("#opt_box").removeAttr("checked");
        $("#ess_box").removeAttr("checked");
    break;    
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be  `$("#opt_box").attr("checked", "checked")`; and not  `$("#opt_box").attr({checked: "checked"});`. See if that is the case. 
 Also you need to pass the parameter to your method `onchange="filter_user_trainings(<put selected option from dropdown here>);"`

Comment: It works well. I have problem with the checkboxes' onclick/onchange event

Comment: u can try it using jQuery like 
$("#opt_box").change(function(){
// your required code
 });

Answer (score 0):

Get a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sTmTR/2/).
I refactored your code a bit, but that's not the important part.

1. You should [alter the "checked" **property** instead of the attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)
2. You must trigger the change event yourself, because [that's not getting fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136000/set-prop-without-triggering-change) when setting either the property nor attribute via JS

So you must trigger the change event on target checkboxes and **after that** re-set the property to your desired value (like in my fiddle), because triggering the change event naturally also changes the checkbox' state.

```
$checkboxes.prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
```

**Update:** Ok, seems like triggering a change with JS actually doesn't change the checkbox' property, so you can trigger a change after the value has been set and get the correct value (which is the current state). Updated my fiddle.